# How to select a value based on a specific key value

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the array:

```
Array
(
[0] ( Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Bag
        [flag] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Screen
        [flag] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => HD
        [flag] => 0
    )

)
```

What I need to get is the value of the "flag" (3rd) column in this array, based on the value of the "id" (1st) column in this array.

Another example, ID #2's name would be "Screen". However when using `$items[2]['name']` obviously returns HD. Any ideas on where to go from there?

The current code used to generate the above output is:

```
$items = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($flagresult)) {
$items[] = array($row['id'], 'name' => $row['name'], 'flag' => $row['flag']);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: So loop through the array, testing the id value of each element till you find the one you want, and then get the relevant values from that element

Comment: If possible you may want to move the `id` to the key when creating the array. Then you could just do `$arr[$id]['flag']` to access it

Comment: why not use the id's as key in the first place? It would make your `$items[2]['name']` work as expected, and be much more efficient than looping or searching...

Comment: I definitely like that idea and have modified my code accordingly!

Comment: What do you mean did I give up? The post above yours indicated that I liked the idea and modified my code accordingly. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `array_column()` you can index the array by `id`:

```
$items = array_column($items, null, 'id');
echo $items[2]['name'];
echo $items[2]['flag'];
```

But why not do this when you create the array?  First, only select the fields you need `SELECT id, name, flag FROM ...` Then just fetch an associative array with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and use the `id` as the key:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($flagresult)) {
    $items[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_search`.
Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful

```
$key = array_search(2, array_column($items, 'id'),true);
echo $items[$key]['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the id of your array as the index of your array:

```
$items = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($flagresult)) {
    $items[$row['id']] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'flag' => $row['flag']);
}
```